# Does anyone know if this counts as assault?

Tags: united-states, assault

I saw this YouTube video where a reporter tries to follow a man into his business. The man punches the reporter in the face. Does anyone know if this was ever taken to court? If not, would it likely count as assault? Assume the location is in the US.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kshb4WVCDPo (about 25 seconds in)

Answer (score 2):

Even before you get to the punch, it is. Actual offensive contact is battery, and the attempt (threat) to commit battery is assault. Assault might be justified to prevent trespass, but the first assault happened right at the start (grabbing the reporter) where trespass is absolutely not an issue. Additionally, since this is at a public place of business, a property owner has to first withdraw the implicit permission to enter, and the force necessary to prevent the trespass has to be "reasonably minimal" (there are clearly less forceful alternatives to a smack in the face).